# php imagick error (ImageMagick 6.5.4 library for php version 5.3.1.3 and wamp server ,system 32 bit)

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I have installed ImageMagick 6.5.4 library for php version 5.3.1.3 and wamp server, system 32 bit.

I tried to do blur on images and draw circles and some primitives and everything go in the right way. But when I tried some code which have imagick statement I have this result

> Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in C:\wamp\www\t\code.php on line 2

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: if you're still having problems then [VC9 compiled ImageMagick_v6.8 and PHP ext lib](http://valokuva.org/~mikko/imagick-php54-php53.tgz). WAMPserver is VC9 compiled as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagick needs to be activated in your php.ini file and in your case you need the correct imagick.dll file to go with it.
This can be a frustrating business as you need the correct .dll to go with the php version and it has to be compiled with the correct version of something - can not remember exactly what now.

It is also not very well supported and I find very frustrating to use. I recomend you stick with exec( ) and the command line.

Comment: i can see php-imagick.dll in php exctentions and it's checked.... what can i do??.... i'm working in my graduation project which based in online image processing  using php and imagemagick ,,

Comment: As I say you need a Imagick dll to get Imagick to work - Imagick is an API for Imagemagick with php. I just use exec( ) for everything and have XAMPP on my local host. I have lots of examples on my website http://www.rubblewebs.co.uk/imagemagick/index.php using exec(), batch scripts and a few Imagick and GD ones. If you really want to use Imagick you will have to search the web for Imagick.dll which is for your version of php and try some different ones unil you find one that works.

Comment: i visit this websites manytimes and i tried some of it's examples it great one.... i will try to search imagick.dll and i hope to find it as soon as possible :)
thanks

Comment: `can not remember exactly what now.` Visual C++ libraries. VC8, VC9, VC10.

Comment: Thats what I was thinking of @DoSparKot